# python String replace function argument

Tags: python

```
str1 = ["is" , "first"]       
str2 = ["was" , "second"]          
str3 = "he is doing his first year graduation"       
for i in RANGE(len(str1)):      
str4 = str3.replace(str1[i],str2[i])
```

Due to the immutable property only the second change ("first" to "second"). How can i make both changes together. Actually I have a huge size of string. I'm new to python, please help me

Answer (score 3):

Simply assign the last line to `str3`:

```
str1 = ["is" , "first"]       
str2 = ["was" , "second"]          
str3 = "he is doing his first year graduation"       
for i in range(len(str1)):      
    str3 = str3.replace(str1[i],str2[i])  

print str3  # he was doing hwas second year graduation
```

Pay attention that the *is* in the word "his" is also being replaced!

If you want an "exact" matching, use the regex module:

```
import re

str1 = ["is" , "first"]       
str2 = ["was" , "second"]          
str3 = "he is doing his first year graduation"       
for i in range(len(str1)):      
    str3 = re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(str1[i]),str2[i], str3)  

print str3  # he was doing his second year graduation
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in one line by applying `reduce` and `lambda`:

`ans = reduce(lambda n, (old, new): n.replace(old, new), zip(str1,str2), str3)`

example:

```
>>> str1 = ["is", "first"]
>>> str2 = ["was", "second"]
>>> str3 = "he is doing his first year graduation"
>>> ans = reduce(lambda n, (old, new): n.replace(old, new), zip(str1,str2), str3)
>>> ans
'he was doing hwas second year graduation'
```

However, I suppose in your origin design `"his"` would become `"hwas"`, so you might still need to use `re.sub` as suggested by others:

```
>>> import re
>>> ans = reduce(lambda n, (old, new): re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(old), new, n), zip(str1,str2), str3)
>>> ans
'he was doing his second year graduation'
```

Comment: @Harvey `izip()` doesn't generate a `list`, so it should not be able to fit in `reduce()` function, right?

Comment: It returns an iterable which is all that reduce needs. Python3's zip() is actually Python2's itertools.izip(). `from itertools import izip; print(reduce(lambda x,y: x + "".join(y), izip("abc","123"), ""))` prints `a1b2c3`

Answer (score 0):

an alternative to @alfasin's answer is to enumerate the list, this yields same end result! Also, note that str3 is overwritten in each iteration of the `for` loop, no `str4`variable used

```
str1 = ["is" , "first"]       
str2 = ["was" , "second"]          
str3 = "he is doing his first year graduation"       
for idx, s in enumerate(str1):      
    str3 = str3.replace(s,str2[idx])  

print str3  # he was doing hwas second year graduation
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not an issue of immutability. You keep creating a new str4 with only the latest replace. You want to create str4 once, and update it a few times. For example

```
str1 = ["is", "first"]
str2 = ["was", "second"]
str3 = "he is doing his first year graduation"
str4 = str3
for i in range(len(str1)):
    str4 = str4.replace(str1[i], str2[i])
```

You'll notice this has a bug where "his" becomes "hwas" (I assume that's a bug). You could use regexes to only match words, but you're likely better off using dictionaries.

Create a dictionary with {str1[i]:str2[i]} for each i. Then iterate through each word in str3 replacing it with its value in the dictionary.